# How to resolve SOQL injection problem in map based dynamic query in apex

Tags: apex, soql, batch, soql-injection

I am getting SOQL injection vulnerability in security scanning in a map based dynamic query in batch apex. Please let me know if any workaround for this. Below is the code-

```
global ChangeOwner(String appId){
        this.AppId = appId;
        this.QueryMap= new Map<String, String>{
            'Sample1__c' => 'Select Id From Sample1__c where App__c=\''+ appId +'\'',
            'Sample2__c' => 'Select Id From Sample2__c where Sample1__r.App__c=\''+ appId +'\'',
            'Sample3__c' => 'Select Id From Sample3__c where Sample2__r.Sample1__r.App__c=\''+ appId +'\'',
            'Sample4__c' => 'Select Id From Sample4__c where Sample1__r.App__c=\''+ appId +'\'',
        };
        this.ObjectList = new List<String>(QueryMap.keySet());       
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String strObject = '';
        if(this.ObjectList.size() > this.Index)
            strObject = this.ObjectList.get(this.Index);
        
        if(QueryMap.ContainsKey(strObject))
            strQuery = QueryMap.get(strObject);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(strQuery);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yours is a(n almost) "textbook" example of a SOQL injection vulnerability.

From https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm :

> To prevent a SOQL injection attack, avoid using dynamic SOQL queries. Instead, use static queries and binding variables.
>
> ...
>
> If you must use dynamic SOQL, use the escapeSingleQuotes method to sanitize user-supplied input. This method adds the escape character () to all single quotation marks in a string that is passed in from a user. The method ensures that all single quotation marks are treated as enclosing strings, instead of database commands.

I don't believe I've ever used a Map like you show to do queries, but according to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm :

> You can instead resolve the variable field into a string and use the string in your dynamic SOQL query:
>
> ```
> String resolvedField1 = myVariable.field1__c;
> List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE field1__c =  :resolvedField1');
> ```

Since your `appId` is alrady a String, you should be able to change to:

```
this.QueryMap= new Map<String, String>{
    'Sample1__c' => 'Select Id From Sample1__c where App__c= :appId',
    ...
}
```

If not, then use `String.escapeSingleQuotes`.